# convert tibble to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Im new to R and have received data from others with a much better level of R than me.
I need to due some simple descriptive statistic with deadline tomorrow and noticed that the data is in "tibble" format and I would like it as a dataframe instead. Can anybody help? its probably very simple but my skills in tidyverse are still very limited - but working on it:)

The tibble is as i would like it to be with 165 rows (one for each patient) and 16 columns.
I would just like it to be a dataframe.

Thank you for your time

I tried the very simple

```
data_dataframe <- as.data.frame(model_data)
```

But didnt work.

My str out is:

```
> str(model_data)
tibble [165 × 16] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ PatientID         : Factor w/ 165 levels "Patient_001",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ VAS_baseline      : num [1:165] NA 99 25 75 50 50 90 81 80 100 ...
$ VAS_followup_30   : num [1:165] 75 95 53 85 88 92 98 NA NA 80 ...
$ VAS_followup_180  : num [1:165] 95 83 35 NA 94 68 98 NA NA 100 ...
$ Index_baseline    : num [1:165] NA 1 0.847 1 0.813 0.826 0.967 1 0.96 0.952 ...
$ Index_followup_30 : num [1:165] 0.967 0.919 0.764 0.919 1 0.96 1 NA NA 0.919 ...
$ Index_followup_180: num [1:165] 1 0.88 0.728 NA 1 1 1 NA NA 0.952 ...
$ Age               : num [1:165] 68 74 61 64 69 55 74 68 79 66 ...
$ Group             : Factor w/ 3 levels "Group_1","Group_2",..: 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 2 ...
$ Surgeon           : Factor w/ 6 levels "Surgeon_1","Surgeon_2",..: 1 3 1 1 5 3 1 6 4 6 ...
$ VAS_to_30         : num [1:165] NA -4 28 10 38 42 8 NA NA -20 ...
$ VAS_to_180        : num [1:165] NA -16 10 NA 44 18 8 NA NA 0 ...
$ VAS_30_to_180     : num [1:165] 20 -12 -18 NA 6 -24 0 NA NA 20 ...
$ Index_to_30       : num [1:165] NA -0.081 -0.083 -0.081 0.187 ...
$ Index_to_180      : num [1:165] NA -0.12 -0.119 NA 0.187 0.174 0.033 NA NA 0 ...
$ Index_30_to_180   : num [1:165] 0.033 -0.039 -0.036
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What does "didn't work" mean to you, why don't you think it worked?

Comment: You did `str(model_data)` but your new object is `data_dataframe`. look at `str(data_dataframe)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the above code the str output change to data frame, but when i try to simple summary stat like using tapply:  tapply(data_dataframe$Index_baseline,sd, na.rm=TRUE) it comes with an error:...Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors ...and if i try to use the st funktion from the vtable package to get mean and sd it lists each patient ID number per row: Patient_001, Patient_002...with a number of 1 and procentage of 0.6% per row instead of the PatientID as a single row variable, so something seems to be wrong

Comment: Your error doesn't actually seem to be related to whether it's a tibble (which is a type of data frame) or a base data frame. Based on your comment, you're calling `tapply` on a vector and with seemingly incorrect arguments. What are you expecting to happen there? If you want the standard deviation of `index_baseline`, just call `sd(data_dataframe$index_baseline)` or whatever it is you're trying to do

Comment: `tapply` is for doing grouped operations. At a minimum, it needs arguments `X`: a vector to operate on, `INDEX`: a vector that defines the groups, and `FUN`, the function to apply to each group. You're providing `X` and `FUN`, but not a grouping variable. As camille says, if you don't want grouping, use `sd()` directly, you don't need `tapply`. If you do want to group by, say, the `Group` column then use `tapply(data_dataframe$Index_baseline, INDEX = data_dataframe$Group, sd, na.rm = TRUE)`